# How to write the sum of series as Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How to write the sum of series as Laurent series ?

$-\frac12\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac z2)^n+-\frac4z\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z^{-2})^n$

I have somehow a blackout, how can I combine $2$ pieces together, I can change the term in the second one as $(-z^2)^n$ and $n$ from $-\infty$ to $0$ but I can't still write it as only one sum

the original exercise is from here

[Laurent Series Expansion of $\frac{-3z^2+8z+1}{(z-2)(z^2+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289866/laurent-series-expansion-of-frac-3z28z1z-2z21)

Comment: You can write it in the form "$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$, where [description of the coefficients]". But typically, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}z^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\cdot 4 z^{-(2n+1)}$$ or the form you have is considered "Laurent enough".

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thanks I almost freaked out

Comment: Just sayin': For the series here, if you really want, you can write the coefficients as a closed formula. But such a closed formula would be **much** less readable.